# How to scrape specific data from scrape with simple html dom parser

Tags: php, html, parsing, variables

I am trying to scrape the datas from a webpage, but I get need to get all the data in [this link](http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungen/unsere_leistungen/buergerstiftungsfinder).

```
include 'simple_html_dom.php';
$html1 = file_get_html('http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungen/unsere_leistungen/buergerstiftungsfinder');

$info1 = $html1->find('b[class=[what to enter herer ]',0);
```

I need to get all the data out of [this site](http://www.aktive-buergerschaft.de/buergerstiftungen/unsere_leistungen/buergerstiftungsfinder).

```
Bürgerstiftung Lebensraum Aachen
    rechtsfähige Stiftung des bürgerlichen Rechts
    Ansprechpartner: Hubert Schramm
    Alexanderstr. 69/ 71
    52062 Aachen
    Telefon: 0241 - 4500130
    Telefax: 0241 - 4500131
    Email: info@buergerstiftung-aachen.de
    www.buergerstiftung-aachen.de
    >> Weitere Details zu dieser Stiftung

Bürgerstiftung Achim
    rechtsfähige Stiftung des bürgerlichen Rechts
    Ansprechpartner: Helga Kühn
    Rotkehlchenstr. 72
    28832 Achim
    Telefon: 04202-84981
    Telefax: 04202-955210
    Email: info@buergerstiftung-achim.de
    www.buergerstiftung-achim.de
    >> Weitere Details zu dieser Stiftung
```

I need to have the data that are "behind" the link - is there any way to do this with a easy and understandable parser - one that can be understood and written by a newbie!?

Comment: want to  have - also!!- the data that is behind the link >> weitere Details...Note this is a link that is in each adress-record.

Comment: How about scrape the result page and gather the URL that is associated with the "weitere Details" link and then for each link open the page and scrape it until all links done.. that's what i do .. but in .net.

Comment: hi ppumkin - many thanks - this is a very interesting idea! I would love to learn more bout your approach. Can you give some more hints. That would be great!

Comment: The site in question is clearly copyrighted so responders may wish to consider the ethical issues involved in assisting the OP in intellectual property theft.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Seems to be written in the [documentation](http://simplehtmldom.sourceforge.net/#fragment-13):

```
$html1->find('b[class=info]',0)->innertext;
```

Answer (score 7):

Your provided links are down,
I will suggest you to use the native PHP "[DOM](http://www.php.net/manual/en/book.dom.php)" Extension instead of "simple html parser", it will be much faster and easier ;)
I had a look at the page using googlecache, you can use something like:-

```
$doc = new DOMDocument;
@$doc->loadHTMLFile('...URL....'); // Using the @ operator to hide parse errors
$contents = $doc->getElementById('content')->nodeValue; // Text contents of #content
```

Comment: hello Salman, unfortunatley the pages are down at the moment. I hope that they will get online soon. Anyway - many many thanks for the provided information. i will test this - as soon the site is up  again! greeetings

Comment: Many Many Thanks for the new hints. Great to hear from you. As soon as the site is up i will run the programme. Again mille grazie!! Greetings Zero

Comment: Hello dear SalmanPK - you are very very supportive. Many many thanks for your great great help so far! The site is up again!! Now we can have a closer look at the site... I look forward to hear from you.. Best regards zero

Answer (score 2):

From what i can quickly glance you need to loop through the <dl> tags in #content, then the dt and dd.

```
foreach ($html->find('#content dl') as $item) {
     $info = $item->find('dd');
     foreach ($info as $info_item) {..}
}
```

Using the simple_html_dom library

Answer (score 1):

XPath makes scraping ridiculously easy, and allows for some changes in the HTML document to not affect you. For example, to pull out the names, you'd use a query that looks like:

```
//div[id='content']/d1/dt
```

A simple [Google search](http://www.google.co.za/search?q=xpath%20html%20scraping) will give you plenty of tutorials

Answer (score 1):

@zero: there is good site to try out scrapping a site using both php and python...pretty helpful site atleast to me:- 
http://scraperwiki.com/

Answer (score -1):

I'd use WWW:Mechanize

http://search.cpan.org/dist/WWW-Mechanize/lib/WWW/Mechanize.pm

Comment: Another -1 for a Perl answer in a PHP question. Just because you *can* do something doesn't mean you *should*.

Comment: hello Rob hello Meagar - thx for your comments - well i would try this with Mech - but this goes a bit over my head! I should need some hints and help. Eamorr - thx for all